# Lat / Long coordinates using one reference point

Tags: geolocation, geocoding, latitude-longitude, geojson

I am interested in finding Lat/Long coordinates of two points (A and B). If I have one GeoJSON reference point A (e.g., x,y) and B is a defined distance d (e.g., 10 meters) away from A, is it possible to determine the GeoJSON (Lat/Long) coordinates for B, such that B = (x,y)+d?

[Check here to see example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHX4T.png)

Comment: No you cant , because from a fixed point A and at a distance , there can be N number of points in a circle. Imagine drawing a circle with centre A and with radius distance ,i hope you understand what i mean to say

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response. I agree if its a circle there are many numbers of points, however, if I already know the direction that B will be 90 degrees from A, it would be one point at distance 'd'. Is there a way to determine the lat/long from a known coordinate? Thnx.